# Training matrix for SVM in OpenCv

Tags: svm, training-data

My features are  the normalized rgb values that is it contains values in the range of 0 to 0.1.I have declared the training matrix to be CV_64FC1. It contains 1000 rows and 60 columns but with decimal values like 0.3333 or 0.2789. Now I read in the OpenCv docs that the training matrix has to be of float type but my matrix is of type double. How to give this matrix to the SVM for training without converting to float

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your variables to float type

Comment: I tried using trainingMatrix.convertTo(trainingMatrix,CV_32FC1) but now svm gives the error bad argument.